# how to do I install cuda on 18.10,

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, 18.10, compiler

I have a lenovo T540p thinkpad, with an NVIDIA GK208M [GeForce GT 730M], 
I tried to install cuda tool-kit version 10, but the install script says I have the wrong compiler. It doesnt specify the proper compiler, and the nvidia website doesnt list a version compatable with ubuntu 18.10, it also states I am attempting to do an unsupported installation. Given my scenario, how can I install a cuda toolkit? what cuda version should I use?

Answer (score 1):

See [CUDA Inst Guide section 1.2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) for the GCC compilers supported for each Ubuntu release.  The latest supported Ubuntu release is 18.04, kernel 4.15 with gcc version 7.3.0 and glibc version 2.27.  If you cannot use a supported distribution, you will need to either downgrade to a supported tool version (probably works), or test the supplied tool version for problems (may work).  Your GPU supports CUDA 10,  with compute capability of 3.0, so that whould not be a problem.